# D3.js Synchronized Zoom Across Multiple Graphs

Tags: javascript, node.js, d3.js, zooming, interaction

I want to make a line chart to zoom/pan in sync with multiple web pages.

[image]

These client has same Javascript and HTML source.
User zooms or pan on client A, message which is day time of domain of data is sent to the other and sender(blue line on above fig), and graph of received clients will be change simultaneously . Of course, other clients can do the same.
It is similar like a chat application.

Zoom function is:

```
 function zoomed() {
        let msg = [];
        let t = d3.event.transform; //1)

        msg[0] = t.rescaleX(x2).domain()[0].toString(); //2)
        msg[1] = t.rescaleX(x2).domain()[1].toString(); //2)

        sendMessage(msg); //3)
    }
```

1. d3.event.transform catches mouse event.
2. convert to date time and strings.
3. send new scale domain to server.

Server sends received data to all clients:

```
function passiveZoom(rcv){
        let leftend;
        let rightend;
        leftend = new Date(rcv[0]);
        rightend = new Date(rcv[1]);

        x.domain([leftend, rightend]);

        svg.select(".line").attr("d", valueline);
        svg.select(".axis").call(xAxis);
    }
```

1. Received message from server which contain new day time.
2. set new domain,
3. update the line charts.

With this it is possible to zoom|pan all the line charts.

However, it does not work as required.

If I zoom|pan in client A, client B and client C will be changed. That is ok.

Next, I zoom|pan on client C(orange line on above figure), All graphs change to initial scale and position. Why!?

I assume that the mouse coordinates are not sent to the clients, but how should I handle it when I send the position coordinates of the mouse?

The Zoom|Pan process is forked from  mbostock's block: [Brush & Zoom](https://bl.ocks.org/mbostock/34f08d5e11952a80609169b7917d4172). The sender also changes the range of the X2 domain with `t.rescalex (x2).domain()`.
Since X2 is not used in the drawing, I changed X to x2, but I can only zoom in. I do not understand the meaning of X2.

Would you please let me know how to synchronize all of clients? 
And what is x2?

This code is for clients forked from [Simple line graph with v4](https://bl.ocks.org/d3noob/402dd382a51a4f6eea487f9a35566de0).

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<style>
/* set the CSS */

body {
    font: 12px Arial;
}

path {
    stroke: steelblue;
    stroke-width: 2;
    fill: none;
}

.zoom {
    cursor: move;
    fill: none;
    pointer-events: all;
}

.axis path,
.axis line {
    fill: none;
    stroke: grey;
    stroke-width: 1;
    shape-rendering: crispEdges;
}
</style>

<body>
    <!-- load the d3.js library -->
    <script src="http://d3js.org/d3.v4.min.js"></script>
     <script src="socket.io.js"></script>
    <script>

        //--- Network----
    let rcvT;
    let socket = io.connect('http://localhost:3000'); 

    //Recive event from server
    socket.on("connect", function() {}); 
    socket.on("disconnect", function(client) {}); 
    socket.on("S_to_C_message", function(data) {
        rcvT = data.value;
        passiveZoom(rcvT);

    });
    socket.on("S_to_C_broadcast", function(data) {
        console.log("Rcv broadcast " + data.value);
        rcvT = data.value;
        passiveZoom(rcvT);
    });

    function sendMessage(msg) {
        socket.emit("C_to_S_message", { value: msg }); //send to server
    }

    function sendBroadcast(msg) {
        socket.emit("C_to_S_broadcast", { value: msg }); // send to server
    }

    // --------------------

    // Set the dimensions of the canvas / graph
    var margin = { top: 30, right: 20, bottom: 30, left: 50 },
        width = 600 - margin.left - margin.right,
        height = 270 - margin.top - margin.bottom;

    // Parse the date / time
    var parseDate = d3.timeParse("%d-%b-%y");

    // Set the ranges
    var x = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);
    var y = d3.scaleTime().range([height, 0]);
    var x2 = d3.scaleTime().range([0, width]);

    xAxis = d3.axisBottom(x)
        .tickFormat(d3.timeFormat('%d-%b-%y'))
        .ticks(5);

    // var yAxis = d3.svg.axis().scale(y)
    //     .orient("left").ticks(5);
    yAxis = d3.axisLeft(y);

    // Define the line
    var valueline = d3.line()
        .x(function(d) { return x(d.date); })
        .y(function(d) { return y(d.close); });

    // Adds the svg canvas
    var svg = d3.select("body")
        .append("svg")
        .attr("width", width + margin.left + margin.right)
        .attr("height", height + margin.top + margin.bottom)
        .append("g")
        .attr("transform",
            "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")");

    // Get the data
    d3.csv("data.csv", function(error, data) {
        data.forEach(function(d) {
            d.date = parseDate(d.date);
            d.close = +d.close;
        });

        // Scale the range of the data
        x.domain(d3.extent(data, function(d) { return d.date; }));
        x2.domain(x.domain());
        y.domain([0, d3.max(data, function(d) { return d.close; })]);

        // Add the valueline path.
        svg.append("path")
            .data([data])
            .attr("class", "line")
            .attr("d", valueline);

        // Add the X Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "x axis")
            .attr("transform", "translate(0," + height + ")")
            .call(xAxis);

        // Add the Y Axis
        svg.append("g")
            .attr("class", "y axis")
            .call(yAxis);

    });
    //follow is zoom method------------------
    zoom = d3.zoom()
        .scaleExtent([1, 45])
        .translateExtent([
            [0, 0],
            [width, height]
        ])
        .extent([
            [0, 0],
            [width, height]
        ])
        .on("zoom", zoomed);

    svg.append("rect")
        .attr("class", "zoom")
        .attr("width", width)
        .attr("height", height)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + margin.left + "," + margin.top + ")")
        .call(zoom);

    function zoomed() {
        let msg = [];
        let t = d3.event.transform;

        msg[0] = t.rescaleX(x2).domain()[0].toString();
        msg[1] = t.rescaleX(x2).domain()[1].toString();

        sendMessage(msg);
    }

    function passiveZoom(rcv){
        let start;
        let end;
        start = new Date(rcv[0]);
        end = new Date(rcv[1]);

        x.domain([start, end]);

        svg.select(".line").attr("d", valueline);
        svg.select(".axis").call(xAxis);
    }



    </script>
</body>
```

If you try this code, you should exec in a few bowser windows, and run this node.js script.

```
var http = require("http");
var socketio = require("socket.io");
var fs = require("fs");

console.log("reflector start");


var server = http.createServer(function(req, res) {
     res.writeHead(200, {"Content-Type":"text/html"});
     var output = fs.readFileSync("./index.html", "utf-8");
     res.end(output);
}).listen(process.env.VMC_APP_PORT || 3000);

var io = socketio.listen(server);

io.sockets.on("connection", function (socket) {

  // send message to all
  socket.on("C_to_S_message", function (data) {
    io.sockets.emit("S_to_C_message", {value:data.value});
       console.log("MSG "+data.value);
  });

  // boradcast send to all without sender
  socket.on("C_to_S_broadcast", function (data) {
    socket.broadcast.emit("S_to_C_broadcast", {value:data.value});
  });

  // disconnection
  socket.on("disconnect", function () {
  console.log("disconnect");
  });
});
```

Comment: Not related to your question: *why* are you planning this? Are those client machines commanded by real, human users? If "yes" this seems to deliver a bad UX in my opinion... (+1 for a nicely written question anyway)

Comment: By the way, `x2` is the time scale used by the brush, which is the lower part of that chart, called "context". You can see that `x2` domain never changes (but `x` domain does).

Comment: Thanks Gerardo. I want to display the data of multiple time series (day-population, date-GDP, etc) together in one Web page.
Each client is loaded with <iframe>.

Comment: Ouch miss type. I correct the code. " msg[0] = t.rescaleX(x).domain()[0].toString();" -> " msg[0] = t.rescaleX(x2).domain()[0].toString();" if it was "rescaleX(x)", interaction is zoom in only.

Comment: To dig further into what has been kicked off by @Gerardo: Why the hassle of the server roundtrip? Why not just keep it on the client whereby reducing / avoiding latencies? Don't get me wrong, no harm meant! Just trying to comprehend what is going on and maybe learn a bit myself ;-)

Comment: In `passiveZoom` change the zoom attached to the SVG element, this will call the zoom callback, don't communicate the dates but the zoom parameters

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Assuming I understand the problem,

The (first) problem is that you are not updating (the) `zoom` itself.

Where `d3.zoom` is used, it often just keeps track of current zoom state rather than applying a transform on a container directly. In the brush and zoom example, the zoom is applied by re-scaling the data - not by applying an SVG transform to the container. Using that example, we can see that when we brush, we also call:

```
svg.select(".zoom").call(zoom.transform, someZoomTransform);
```

This:

- updates the zoom state/identity as tracked by the `zoom` variable
- emits a zoom event, which invokes the zoomed function (which in the brush and zoom example is ignored if a brush triggers it)

If we remove this line, changes in scale state made by brushing don't update the zoom. Brush to a very small domain, then zoom in and see [here](https://bl.ocks.org/Andrew-Reid/949a9ff219d3dba9feae96febccea385).

This is the case in your code, when you update the chart with the `zoomed` function and `d3.event.transform` you aren't updating the zoom state. You are updating the scales - but `zoom` is not updated.

Below I'll demonstrate using one zoom to update another. *Note: if each zoomed function calls the others, we'll enter an infinite loop. With brush and zoom we could see if the trigger was a brush to see if the zoomed function was needed, below I use d3.event.sourceEvent.target to see if the other zoomed functions need to propagate the zoom*:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var size = 100;
var zoom1 = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.25,4]).on("zoom", zoomed1);
var zoom2 = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.25,4]).on("zoom", zoomed2);

var rect1 = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", size)
  .attr("height", size)
  .attr("x", 10)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .call(zoom1);
var rect2 = svg.append("rect")
  .attr("width", size)
  .attr("height", size)
  .attr("x", 300)
  .attr("y", 10)
  .call(zoom2);

function zoomed1() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  var k = Math.sqrt(t.k);
  rect1.attr("width",size/k).attr("height",size*k);
  
  if(d3.event.sourceEvent.target == this) {
    rect2.call(zoom2.transform,t); 
  }
}
function zoomed2() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  var k = Math.sqrt(t.k);
  rect2.attr("width",size/k).attr("height",size*k);
   
  if(d3.event.sourceEvent.target == this) {
    rect1.call(zoom2.transform,t); 
  }
}
```

```css
rect {
    cursor: pointer;
 stroke: #ccc;
 stroke-width: 10;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
Zoom on one rectangle to update the other.
<svg width="600" height="300"></svg>
```

You might wonder why I hard coded size, why don't I just modify the current size, rather than the original. The answer is that the zoom transform scale is the scale relative to the original state - not the last state. For example, if scale doubles each zoom, and we zoom in 2 times, the scale goes from: k=1 → k=2 → k=4. If we multiply the current size of a shape by the new scale, we get size=1 → size=2 → size=8, this is not correct (and upon zooming out to k=2, we'll double the amount we zoom in, rather than zooming out). The transform is cumulative *already*, we don't want to apply it to a value that has a transform applied on it.

*Applying the transform on a transformed value, rather than the original value, can lead to increasing zoom even when zooming out - this is probably why you have had trouble zooming out*

So, this brings me to the second problem, `x2`. `x2` is the reference, the original value. Yes, as Gerardo notes it is also the scale for the brush in your example, but more importantly, he states that this scale doesn't change. Because of this, `x2` is well suited to be used as a reference scale, to which we can use to transform `x` given a zoom state:

```
x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());
```

What happens here? `transform.rescaleX(x2)` doesn't modify `x2`, it "returns a copy of the continuous scale x whose domain is transformed [given a zoom transformation].([docs](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#transform_rescaleX))". We take the copy's domain and assign it to the `x` scale (range of course remains the same), and by doing so, apply the transform to the `x` scale. *This is essentially the same as my snippet above with the square/rectangles, where I keep a reference value for the initial size of the shapes and apply the transform to this value.*

Let's see this in action with a basic graph/plot with scales rather than plain shapes:

```js
var svg = d3.select("svg");
var data = [[0,300],[1,20],[2,300]];

// Area generators:
var leftArea = d3.area().curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x(function(d) { return leftX(d[0]); })
  
var rightArea = d3.area().curve(d3.curveBasis)
  .x(function(d) { return rightX(d[0]); })

// Scales
var leftX = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,2]).range([0,250]);
var rightX = d3.scaleLinear().domain([0,2]).range([300,550]);

var leftX2 = leftX.copy();
var rightX2 = rightX.copy();

// Zooms
var leftZoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.25,4]).on("zoom", leftZoomed);
var rightZoom = d3.zoom().scaleExtent([0.25,4]).on("zoom", rightZoomed);

// Graphs
var leftGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", leftArea(data))
  .call(leftZoom);
  
var rightGraph = svg.append("path")
  .attr("d", rightArea(data))
  .call(rightZoom);
  
function leftZoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  leftX.domain(t.rescaleX(leftX2).domain());
  leftGraph.attr("d",leftArea(data));
        
  if(d3.event.sourceEvent.target == this) {
    rightGraph.call(rightZoom.transform,t); 
  }
}
function rightZoomed() {
  var t = d3.event.transform;
  rightX.domain(t.rescaleX(rightX2).domain());
  rightGraph.attr("d",rightArea(data));
        
  if(d3.event.sourceEvent.target == this) {
    leftGraph.call(leftZoom.transform,t); 
  }
}
```

```css
path {
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/5.7.0/d3.min.js"></script>
    Zoom on one plot to update the other (zoom on the path area itself)
    <svg width="600" height="300"></svg>
```

Put simply, to synchronize multiple zoomable scaled graphs in one page or across clients, you should be:

- updating each zoom with `selection.call(zoom.transform,transform)`
- rescaling each scale using the current transform and a reference scale.

I haven't dug into trying this with multiple clients and sockets. But, the above should help in explaining how to approach the problem. However, with multiple clients, you might need to modify how I've stopped the infinite loop of zoom events, using or setting a property in the transform object might be the easiest. Also, as rioV8 notes, you should probably be passing the zoom parameters (or better yet, d3.event itself), not the domain, though a domain only option is possible.

With sockets, I did have some trouble in sending objects - I'm not familiar with socket.io, and didn't spend a tonne of time looking, but I got this to work with zoomed and passivezoom functions as so:

```
function zoomed() {
    let t = d3.event.transform;

    // 1. update the scale, same as in brush and zoom:
    x.domain(t.rescaleX(x2).domain());

    // 2. redraw the graph and axis, same as in brush and zoom:
    path.attr("d", area);  // where path is the graph
    svg.select(".xaxis").call(xAxis);

    // 3. Send the transform, if needed:
    if(t.alreadySent == undefined) {
      t.alreadySent = true; // custom property.
      sendMessage([t.k,t.x,t.y,t.alreadySent]);
    }
}

function passiveZoom(rcv){
    // build a transform object (since I was unable to successfully transmit the transform)
    var t = d3.zoomIdentity;
    t.k = rcv[0];
    t.x = rcv[1];
    t.y = rcv[2];
    t.alreadySent = rcv[3];
    //trigger a zoom event (invoke zoomed function with new transform data).
    rect.call(zoom.transform,t);  // where rect is the selection that zoom is called on.
}
```

Rather than sending the event, I send the transform parameters (only) along with a flag to note that the zoom event that a passive zoom function triggers doesn't need to be passed onwards again. This is based in principle exactly on the above snippets.

*No modification to server side script. Here's the [client side](https://gist.github.com/Andrew-Reid/207822f505a77edd1b869ca712daa1cf) that I used - it's more basic than your code, as I stripped out y scales, y axis, csv data source, etc.*

Comment: Hm, I am not yet really happy with this answer: 1) I suppose you are using Firefox, right? [`Event.originalTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget) is [supported ](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/originalTarget) only by that browser. The snippets don't work as expected using Chrome; you see the zooming of one rect at a time but no synchronization. The fix is simple, of course, use [`Event.target`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Event/target) instead. 2) The quoted line, `zoom.transform()` to be specific, does not

Comment: trigger a zoom event. 3) This is more of a matter of style (here starts the nitpicking) but I personally don't like `someZoomIdentity` as *zoom identity* is commonly used to refer to the identity transformation [`d3.zoomIdentity()`](https://github.com/d3/d3-zoom#zoomIdentity).

Comment: @altocumulus Didn't even think to cross platform test last night, modified it by adding a property to the transform to check when propogating the zoom (will take a look at zoom target a bit later, just heading to work). On two, I hadn't thought about that from a technical point, I guess it's fair to say `zoom.transform` emits a zoom event (as stated in the docs)? And the third point, I blanked on the language there, updated, thanks for the review, I'm pretty embarrassed on the first point - though the others are also good criticisms.

Comment: You find myself at least as embarrased on the second point as you are on the first one ;-) I completely overlooked the docs mentioning events for `zoom.transform()`. Yet, I advise against introducing a new property on an internal object. Instead of `d3.event.sourceEvent.originalTarget == this` just use `d3.event.sourceEvent.target == this`.

Comment: Ah, the zoom.transform() events are easy to miss. I've incorporated the sourceEvent.target option, you're right about messing with internals. I can't see why this approach won't work with sockets either - the zoomed element may be the same in each browser, but the target object references will be different.

Comment: Thanks Andrew and altocumulus to join discussion. That is my point.
The `event.transform` event only fires on the current browser. `event.transfom` does not propagate exactly. Even if event.transfom is sent as a message, `event.transfom.rescaleX` is displayed on the console as `"TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'receivedMsg.transform.rescaleX')"` on the receiving side.
Even if you send `event.transform.x, y, k`, the value of k(scale) is calculated from the difference of mouse position, so it will not be synchronized interaction.

Comment: @prophet5, using the techniques that I used in the two snippets, I got this to work across browsers in node with sockets.io - but I had trouble sending objects, so got lazy and sent x,y,k and rebuilt the transform after transmitting - updated the answer with the specifics of my node/sockets.io solution (the only real difference is the use of a passive zoom function to trigger the normal zoom function and how I send the transform, not as an object, but as x,y,k.

Comment: @prophet5, was that update useful (and the rest of the answer clear)? I was able to replicate the snippet in the answer with node/socket.io and multiple clients, as noted in the updated answer - but perhaps I missed something with the simplified code.

Comment: @AndrewReid, Thanks a lot of your cooperation. I've tried it. Launch Client A and Clinet B with different browsers. 1) Zoom on Client A. The interaction propagates to Client B. Both graphs change. It's OK.
2) Then zoom the ClientB. Client A also changes synchronously. it's OK. 3) Zoom Client A again. Ouch! Both graphs return to the last state of the operation of 1).
Is zoomed () not affected by parameter changes from passiveZooom ()?

Comment: @prophet5 I'm unable to replicate- I can move between either client any number of times without issue (tested with 2 and 3 clients, with firefox & chrome - across different and same browsers), the only potential issue would be refreshing a client - then zoom state won't be known. But in your case, I'm not sure how 1) zoom on A, ok 2) zoom on B, ok, 3) zoom on A again, and the zoom resets to initial state is possible: the earlier zoom states are not stored: the only state is the current one. Passive zoom updates zoom, calls zoomed, while applying the transform, same as any zoom event.

Comment: Thanks @AndrewReid ! Finally my code got woks fine.My code had structural defects.
My code called the target graph within the `d3.csv` function. So I did not go well. And rect changed the setting like this. `svg.append ("rect")` .---> `var rect = svg.append ("rect").`. D3 was confused as there are various description methods.
I modified it with reference to your code. Thank you!